# How to recursively search for a file in a remote server

Tags: cmd, windows-server-2008, remote-server

I am using `dir \\pwdf1280\rep\"*.txt" /S` to search for all the txt files in the folder rep. I used the `/S` argument to search for the same in the sub directories,  but the problem is the command runs forever. I am basically writing a perl script which has to find these files along with their timestamp.

Is there any other approach to solve this, or can I improve on the above command?

The problem is the dir command I mentioned above runs forever and does not display files present in `rep's` sub directories. It just displays files present in `rep` directory. I want to search for a file in the `rep's` sub directories.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.

Comment: If you're walking a directory tree, then ... that will be the slow part. But take a look at `File::Find::Rule` if you're thinking perlishly.

Comment: @Sobrique i used `File::Find::Rule` , does the function take UNC paths as argument

Comment: @Sobrique  `@full_pathes = File::Find::Rule->file->name("*.log")->in('\\\pwdfm123\\logs') `   can i pass the UNC path as argument,  it doesn't work , am i doing anything wrong

Comment: @kewin: *"it doesn't work"* is a dreadful description of the problem.

Comment: @Borodin the command doesnt return anything  for some servers and for  some servers the program runs forever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way that might speed the process up is to run the directory search on the remote machine using PowerShell.

```
C:\src\powershell> type .\rc001.ps1
Invoke-Command `
    -ComputerName 'pwdf1280' `
    -Command { Get-ChildItem '\\pwdf1280\rep' -Recurse -Filter '*.txt' } |
    ForEach-Object { $_.FullName }
```

Then, from a cmd script run:

```
C:\src\powershell> powershell -NoProfile -File .\rc001.ps1
```

Alternatives might be to run the `dir` command remotely using `psexec` from SysInternals or `plink` from PuTTY.

Comment: I think you are asking if you can use `\\pwdf1280\rep` as the path for Get-ChildItem. Yes, you can. Try it.

Comment: yeah i  tried it but the error was it does not exist

Comment: Use your system names and directory paths. Do not use `lit`. `Get-ChildItem '\\pwdf1280\rep' -Recurse -Filter '*.txt'`

Comment: I have edited the answer to use your machine and directory paths. Does this work for you?

Comment: no i tried that before it does not work the error was it does not exist

Comment: In what way "it does not work?" Is there any error message?

Comment: I am assuming that if the DIR works, then you have permission and that the directory and files exist. Is the `pwdf1280` machine enabled for PowerShell remoting? If not, then it might report that the machine does not exist.

Comment: yes ,the `dir` is not a shared path ,so i can't directly use the dir path as an unc path ,but there is a shared path which is in the top of the dir's directory, the power shell command works for that shared path but it does not work for its child folders, since those are not  shared path,is there a way to get to the specific folder present inside the shared folder

Comment: This sounds like a permission problem. If you do not have permission to read those directories, then directories, PowerShell, Perl, nor any other language will change that.

Comment: no i don't have a permission problem , i can recursively search using the above powershell command, which i want to restrict to a specific folder rather than searching all the folders within a shared unc path

Comment: Add the directories to the path. `'\\pwdf1280\rep\the\sub\dir'`

Comment: how can i include get-child cmdlet in a perl script , how can i execute it ,like how there `qx` for cmd commands ,and get the output in a variable

Comment: Perl has several ways to run external commands. http://perlhowto.com/executing_external_commands That will not solve the problem since the Perl script, unless you are using psexec or plink, is still running on the local machine. What directories do you see if you do `DIR \\pwdf1280\rep'?

Comment: i can see a list of files , can i use the same DIR command to find file names for instance any `*.html`

Comment: Using `DIR /S *.html` will find those files. Using `Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter '*.html'` will do the same in PowerShell.

Comment: is it possible to reduce the depth to 2 folders for DIR command, i found the same for Get cmdlet

Comment: I do not know of any parameter for `DIR` or `Get-ChildItem` to limit depth. It could be done with more code. What did you find?

Comment: for `Get-ChildItem` i use the `-Depth` parameter, but the problem is i am unable to incorporate this command in my perl script , i tried using backticks to run the command in powershell and return the output  but it does not return anything , i am using PowerShell::Cmdlet  `my $command = PowerShell
    ->new('Get-ChildItem', [Image => '\pwd110\dxx\mlogs\rp\seq\ls\*\*\*'])
    ->command();
my $result = `$command;` `i am unsure how to make this work

Comment: Many thanks. The `-Depth` parameter is not documented in `Get-Help Get-ChildItem -Online`. I have never run PowerShell from Perl.